# How to use Rust structs from other mods

Tags: rust

I defined a structure in a separate file. When I want to use this I do something like this at the top of the file:

```rust
use other_file::StructName;
mod other_file;
```

When I created a function that uses

```rust
fn test(other : StructName) {};
```

I get a warning about using a private type, which is fixed when I use

```rust
fn test(other : other_file::StructName) {};
```

This requires a lot of extra typing though. I can also reexport the module with `pub use` but I would really like to keep it hidden.

How do I correctly include modules to save typing? The Python equivalent to what I want is

```python
from other_file import StructName
```

The following code explains this in two files. It is a stripped down version of some matrix math utils.

geometry.rs:

```rust
use geometry::{Vec3};
mod geometry;

#[deriving(Eq, Clone, Show)]
pub struct Mat4 {
  data : ~[f32]
}

impl Mat4 {

  fn apply_Vec3(&self, other : &Vec3) -> Vec3{
    let x = self.data[0] * other.x + self.data[1] * other.y + self.data[2] * other.z;
    let y = self.data[4] * other.x + self.data[5] * other.y + self.data[6] * other.z;
    let z = self.data[8] * other.x + self.data[9] * other.y + self.data[10]* other.z;
    Vec3::new(x, y, z)
  }
}

#[deriving(Eq, Clone, Show)]
pub struct Transform {
  mat : Mat4
}

impl Transform {
  pub fn apply_Vec3(&self, vec : &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
    self.mat.apply_Vec3(vec)
  }
}
```

transform.rs:

```rust
#[deriving(Eq, Clone, Show)]
pub struct Vec3 {
  x : f32,
  y : f32,
  z : f32
}
impl Vec3 {
  pub fn new(x : f32, y : f32, z : f32) -> Vec3 {
    Vec3{x : x, y : y, z : z}
  }
}
```

When compiling with `rustc --test transform.rs` I get two errors:

```
transform.rs:25:39: 25:43 warning: private type in exported type signature, #[warn(visible_private_types)] on by default
transform.rs:25       pub fn apply_Vec3(&self, vec : &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
                                                      ^~~~
transform.rs:25:48: 25:52 warning: private type in exported type signature, #[warn(visible_private_types)] on by default
transform.rs:25       pub fn apply_Vec3(&self, vec : &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
                                                               ^~~~
```

Comment: Given a warning about returning a private type, this is clearly not quite what you're doing. Can you share your whole code base?

Comment: Updated and added full code example. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're actually *returning* an `other_file::StructName`; you wouldn't get that warning otherwise.

The problem is that from somewhere else, you can't actually access the type for `other_file::StructName`. As you are accessing it, I presume that `StructName` is public, but that's not enough for things outside this module to access it: the module `other_file` needs to be public as well.

Replace

```rust
mod other_file;
```

with

```rust
pub mod other_file;
```

Your `use` statement is correct and does indeed correspond to the Python `from x import y` statement.  (Approximately only; it's an absolute path unless `self` or `super` come into it—those that would be `.foo` or `..foo` in Python.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! You are correct about my struct being public as well as returning other_file::StructName. Sorry for the terrible code snippet. Should have really not been so lazy...

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, everything is private by default with only a few exceptions; see [Visibility and Privacy](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/rust.html#visibility-and-privacy) in the docs for more information. So, the problem is perhaps that your struct `StructName` is private to the `other_file` module.

If you declare the `struct` as `public` in `b.rs`:

```
pub struct StructName {x: int, y: int}
```

You can successfully use it in `a.rs` as you wrote:

```
use b::StructName;
mod b;
fn test (s: StructName) -> int {return s.x + s.y;}
fn main () {
    let s = StructName {x: 1, y: 2};
    let t = test (s);
    println! ("{:i}", t);
}
```

This successfully compiles with Rust 0.9 and outputs `3`.

Comment: "In Rust, everything is private by default." is not true; at present, variants on a public enum and fields on a struct are public by default.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: clarified that and added a link to docs, thank you.