# How do I access "private" struct's field from other files in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust, module, visibility

As advised by my lead programmer, who's not knowledgeable in Rust but knows a lot about OO languages like Java, C#, and such, I should separate the functions and associated methods of a particular "class," in Rust it's more or less a struct, from its model or [definition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) to another file. But I had trouble accessing a struct's field/data member from another file. It feels icky to just attach `pub` before every struct field's name.

```rust
// some_model.rs
// This feels icky
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub name: String,
    pub id: u32,
}
```

Just so other files could access the aforementioned struct above

```rust
// some_adapter.rs
impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn get_id(&self) -> u32 {
        self.id
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.name
    }

    pub fn new(name: &'static str, id: u32) -> Self {
        SomeModel {
            name,
            id
        }
    }
}
```

***So how does one access such fields from a different file?***

Comment: Did you mean to write `impl SomeStruct` in `some_adapter.rs`? If so, please edit the question, because it does not make much sense at the moment. Btw, in Rust it is idiomatic to put a strcut and its impl in the same file. Don't take Rust advice from a Java guru.

Comment: If this is for an assignment, fine, but this is very much _not_ idiomatic to do in Rust. Rust is not OO and Java conventions in most cases don't apply to Rust so I would recommend against doing this in the future.

Comment: I don't get the premises. Is it that in Java and C# the data definition of a class is not in the same file than its methods ?

Comment: In C++, you would have the data definition in the `.h` and the method bodies in the `.cc`. In all other languages I know that have a proper module system, including Rust and Java, you would put everything related to a "class" in a single file. (Note: I don't know C# so I can't comment on their best practice).

Comment: I suspect that there's a misunderstanding between you and the lead. As others mentioned, Java and C# most definitely put the methods and the data in the same file (because they're part of the same class definition). Maybe your lead referred to having two _separate classes_, one for model, and the other for updates. The model class only contains the very basic invariants that can be checked in isolation, and possibly things like serialization annotations. The controller class manages state changes of the model and drives its "business logic".

Comment: Thanks for clearing. Yeah, probably I misunderstood my lead. She's considered good and experienced, and I know I'm inexperienced, as it's apparent in this post.

Thanks to everyone as well. I'm fairly new interacting with Stackoverflow, should I delete this post? Mark it as wrong? Or am I missing some action that needs to be done?

Comment: Contrary to the many statements I see in Rust comments, **Rust is OO** by virtue of the fact it's multi-paradigm. You can implement any of the OO patterns that you can in other languages. However, specific conventions like C++'s separating a class' implementation from its declaration in a header is not something you want to do with Rust. Rust doesn't have header files - so the reasons for separating implementation and header don't apply to Rust.  Your C++ guy is fine thinking OO, but not in trying to shoehorn Rust into arbitrary C++ conventions.

Answer (score 1):

## Warning

Based from the comments I've received, I'll put this at the top

**THIS IS AN UN-RUSTY SOLUTION**

If your lead programmer says you should do the following, or do what's indicate in the question, protest and show them this post.

## Proposed Answer

I've scoured the net for some answers, every link is a piece of the whole puzzle. See the references below the post. And eventually, I think I found an apt solution, without using the much warned [`include!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html).

I used the following syntax profusely:

```
Syntax
Visibility :
     pub
   | pub ( crate )
   | pub ( self )
   | pub ( super )
   | pub ( in SimplePath )
```

At first glance it was confusing for me, and for the others like me who might be perplexed as well, I had posted my findings with a sample code.

The directory, using [broot](https://github.com/Canop/broot)

```
src                     
├──dal                  
│  ├──adapter           
│  │  └──some_adapter.rs
│  ├──adapter.rs        
│  ├──model             
│  │  └──some_model.rs  
│  └──model.rs          
├──dal.rs               
├──lib.rs               
└──main.rs
```

I intended to include numerous sub-directories as well, as I reckoned it might add incidental information to those likely having the same knowledge as I in Rust.

I executed `cargo new visibility_sample`

**dal/model/some_model.rs**

```rust
// dal/model/some_model.rs
pub struct SomeModel {
    // take note of the following syntax
    pub(in super::super) name: &'static str,
    pub(in super::super) id: u32,
}
```

**dal/adapter/some_adapter.rs**

```rust
// dal/adapter/some_adapter.rs

use super::super::model::some_model::SomeModel;

impl SomeModel {
    pub fn get_id(&self) -> u32 {
        self.id
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.name
    }

    pub fn new(name: &'static str, id: u32) -> Self {
        SomeModel {
            name,
            id
        }
    }
}
```

**dal/model.rs**

```rust
// dal/model.rs
pub mod some_model;
```

**dal/adapter.rs**

```rust
// dal/adapter.rs
pub mod some_adapter;
```

**dal.rs**

```rust
// dal.rs
pub mod model;
pub mod adapter;
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
// lib.rs
pub mod dal;
```

And finally **main.rs**

```rust
// main.rs
use visibility_sample::dal::model::some_model::SomeModel;

fn main() {
    let object = SomeModel::new("Mike", 3);
    println!("name: {}, id: {}", object.get_name(), object.get_id());
}
```

running `cargo run`

```
Compiling visibility_sample v0.1.0 (C:\Users\miked\git\visibility_sample)
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.40s
Running `target\debug\visibility_sample.exe`

name: Mike, id: 3
```

**but** if **main.rs** has the following code:

```rust
// main.rs
use visibility_sample::dal::model::some_model::SomeModel;

fn main() {
    let object = SomeModel::new("Mike", 3);
    println!("name: {}, id: {}", object.name, object.id);
}
```

Powershell prints out Rust compiler's beautiful and informative error printing:

```
error[E0616]: field `name` of struct `SomeModel` is private
 --> src\main.rs:5:41
  |
5 |     println!("name: {}, id: {}", object.name, object.id);
  |                                         ^^^^ private field

error[E0616]: field `id` of struct `SomeModel` is private
 --> src\main.rs:5:54
  |
5 |     println!("name: {}, id: {}", object.name, object.id);
  |                                                      ^^ private field

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I placed "" quotation marks in the title for "private" because I'm not certain whether that word is still applicable with the term I'm trying to convey with my posted solution.

#### References

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/implement-private-struct-in-different-files/29407

[Move struct into a separate file without splitting into a separate module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010796/move-struct-into-a-separate-file-without-splitting-into-a-separate-module)

[Proper way to use rust structs from other mods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490954/proper-way-to-use-rust-structs-from-other-mods)

#### P.S.

Perhaps to those gifted and keen, they can easily understand the solution with a few or even a single link in my references on their own, but to someone like me, I have to read these links a whole lot and repeatedly get back to it for tinkering on my own.

Comment: I think you deserve credit for your effort in researching and elaborating the solution. At the same time, I honestly don't understand what problem you solved with the separation and the additional complexity you introduced. That approach isn't idiomatic Rust and I would advise against its use without a good explanation of what it accomplishes.

Comment: This isn't the right answer. The right answer is to code in Rust, not to imitate another language. There are many high quality repositories you can use as inspiration and example of best practice and **none** of them separate structs and implementations in different files.

Comment: Do you guys think it’s better if I just delete this post?